# Using context parameter with django-simple-menu

Tags: python, django

I want to make a menu in my django app that is changing depending on the page that is being viewed. I'm trying to use Django-simple-menu for this. 
I'm struggeling to get the URL parameters to be accesible in my menus.py.
This is the code I have so far and want to replace the 'company' string with a parameter coming from my URL parameters. Is this possible or is it better to create a menu in my views and assign it to the context?

```
hier = Hierachy.get_root_nodes().filter(company__slug= 'company')
for site in hier:
children = list()
for plant in site.get_children():
    children.append(MenuItem(plant.name,
             reverse('pha:companyHierarchy', args=[plant.company.slug, plant.slug,]),
             weight=10,
             icon="user"))
Menu.add_item("study", MenuItem(site.name, reverse('pha:companyHierarchy', args=[site.company.slug, site.slug,]),
                                       weight=10,
                                       icon="tools",
                                       children=children))
```

Answer (score 0):

After some messing around I found the following solution in writing some middleware.

```
class SimpleMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, func, args, kwargs):
        Menu.items.clear()
        hier = Hierachy.get_root_nodes().filter(company__slug= kwargs['slug'])
        for site in hier:
            children = list()
            for plant in site.get_children():
                children.append(MenuItem(plant.name,
                 reverse('pha:companyHierarchy', args=[plant.company.slug, plant.slug,]),
                 weight=10,
                 icon="user"))
            Menu.add_item("study", MenuItem(site.name, reverse('pha:companyHierarchy', args=[site.company.slug, site.slug,]),
                                           weight=10,
                                           icon="tools",
                                           children=children))

    return None
```

This is the code for the template
menu.html

```
                    {% if menus.study %}
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Studies
                        </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    {% for nodeMenu in menus.study %}
                        {% if nodeMenu.children %}
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="{{nodeMenu.url}}">{{nodeMenu.title}}</a>
                                <!-- Get plants and studies --> 

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    {% for child in nodeMenu.children %}
                                    <li><a href="{{child.url}}">{{child.title}}</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        {% else %}
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="{{nodeMenu.url}}">{{nodeMenu.title}}</a>

                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>

                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I'm trying to make something similar than you. How did you integer this middleware in your html code ? Especially in your block menu code ? I'm getting some troubles in this part.

Comment: You can use it in your html like the normal menu. You will need to add your middelware in your settings. This needs to be done in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [].

Comment: Ok ! Could you just post your html menu in your question ? In order to see How you called the middleware ?

Comment: I added the code for the template using this menu. However you don't need to call the middleware in the html. You need to add this middleware to your settings.py. See django documentation on middleware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/